# Taylor Series Method for a DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I'm going through a practice exam which has solutions and I'm a bit confused about this question:

*Write down the third order Taylor series method for the differential equation*

$y'(x)=-y+x+1, \ \ 0\le x\le1, \ \ y(0)=1.$

*Compute three steps using* $h=0.1$.

The solutions computes derivatives as $ \displaystyle f(x,y)=-y+x+1, \frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)=y-x,\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x,y)=-y+x.$

I don't understand how on earth this was achieved. Is there a different type of differentiation at play here?

When I did it I obtained $ \displaystyle f(x,y)=-y+x+1, \frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)=-y'+1,\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x,y)=-y''$. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that 
$$y'=-y+x+1$$
So you found that 
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)=-y'+1$$
You can substitute, which will give you 
$$y'=y-x$$
Same with the second derivative $(f''=y')$.

Comment: Ohh right, knew it would be something silly, thanks!